# Using $this when not in object context calling method inside class

Tags: php, class, object

I have this line of code that calls a method of buildField from a class name called Field

```
$field_dictionary[$key] = Field::buildField($key, $request);
```

In Field class here is my buildField method

```
public function buildField($key, $request) {

    $field_vocabulary = [];

    $image = $_FILES[$key];
    $image['tmp_name']['image'] = true;
    // Calling this another method from same class
    $field = $this->sanitizeFieldRows($image['tmp_name'], $request->post($key . '_name'), $request->post($key . '_description'));

    $field_vocabulary['name'] = implode('|', $field->field_1);
    $field_vocabulary['description'] = implode('|', $field->field_2);
    $field_vocabulary['image'] = implode('|', $field->reference);

    return $field_vocabulary;
}
```

In that code, there's a this line

```
$field = $this->sanitizeFieldRows($image['tmp_name'], $request->post($key . '_name'), $request->post($key . '_description'));
```

I'm calling another method from the same class. It does some function I just removed since it's so long.

```
public function sanitizeFieldRows($reference, $field_1, $field_2 = null) {

    // Some code etc.....
    // Outputs an object
    return (object) $output;
}
```

But the thing is, I'm calling `$this->sanitizeFieldRows($par1,$par2,$par3)` but it prompts an error saying:

```
Using $this when not in object context in
```

But when I did `Field::sanitizeFieldRows($par1,$par2,$par3)` it works, but these method is in the same object yet it's not the static method that I'm calling.

Anything wrong with this?

Here's the same questions:

[Using $this when not in object context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026204/using-this-when-not-in-object-context)

[Using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840695/using-this-when-not-in-object-context)

[Using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8060727/using-this-when-not-in-object-context)

[PHP using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27463584/php-using-this-when-not-in-object-context)

[Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805327/fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context)

[Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context explanation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23438880/fatal-error-using-this-when-not-in-object-context-explanation)

[Using $this when not in object context php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30596469/using-this-when-not-in-object-context-php)

Comment: Did you instanciate your class ? You can use `self::sanitizeFieldRows($par1,$par2,$par3)` if you are in static mode.

Comment: ^ Thanks for this also @Vincent Decaux, learned something today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since buildField is a static method the $this variable is not available in its scope.

> Because static methods are callable without an instance of the object created, the pseudo-variable $this is not available inside the method declared as static.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: OH RIGHT! I forgot about that, Wonder why I'm calling as `::` instead of creating the `$field = new Field` thing. Silly me.